# Trigger a custom event Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working in a jQuery plugin and tried to trigger a custom event after insert a jQuery Dom Element in body.. but the events never occurs..

Is this possible without user interact?

My code is:

```
var $div = $( '<div />' ), $container = $div.clone();

$container.text( 'test' ).appendTo( 'body' );
$.event.trigger( 'ContainerInit', [ $container ]);

$( document ).on( 'ContainerInit', function( e, $elementContainer ) {
   alert( 'test here!' );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $div = $('<div />'),
               $container = $div.clone();

    $container.text('test').appendTo('body');

    // you should provide a selector to the handler!
    $(document).on('ContainerInit', 'div', function(e, $elementContainer) {
       // console.log is better than alert
       console.log('test here!');
    });

    // trigger event only after assigning handler using correct way to trigger!
    $container.trigger('ContainerInit', [$container]);
});
```

[check here](http://jsbin.com/cadugoyayu/1/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: You should add explanation along with your code, otherwise it may not be clear to OP what you actually changed and why.